# Cannot display count of ul li in div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some Jquery that finds the amount of list `<li>` items in a `<ul>`. I would like to show the result/count in a div with a class, but the code I have so far is not working? When I alert the result its fine.

The result should be displayed where the text 'Test' is but it just shows 'Test' not the count. When I take the div out of the id of `result-item-1` etc it does work.

Here is a [JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/RS41/ro7umxL2/3/).

The code so far is:

```
<div id="result-item-1" class="search" data-search-position="1" style="width: 50%;">
   <div class='item-colours-result'>
      <ul class="">
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="numberOfColours">Test</div>
</div>

<div id="result-item-2" class="search" data-search-position="2" style="width: 50%;">
   <div class='item-colours-result'>
      <ul class="">
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="numberOfColours">Test</div>
</div>

<div id="result-item-3" class="search" data-search-position="3" style="width: 50%;">
   <div class='item-colours-result'>
      <ul class="">
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
         <li>4</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="numberOfColours">Test</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.search').each(function(index, item) {
        var colorCount = $(item).find('.item-colours-result ul li').length;
        //alert(item.id+':'+colorCount)
        $(item).attr('data-search-position', colorCount);
        $(this).next(".numberOfColours").html(colorCount + '&nbsp;' + 'Colours');
    })
});
```

Comment: `$(this).next(".numberOfColours")` - Why `this`? Why `.next()`?

Comment: Question updated - no errors in console

Comment: @Andreas to find the next element of that class

Comment: What is `this`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .find() instead of .next()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.search').each(function(index, item) {
        var colorCount = $(item).find('.item-colours-result ul li').length;
        //alert(item.id+':'+colorCount)
        $(item).attr('data-search-position', colorCount);
        $(this).find(".numberOfColours").html(colorCount + '&nbsp;' + 'Colours');
    })
});
```

`.next()` finds the next matching **sibling** (see [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/next/)), while `.find()` searches within the parent. The div `.numberOfColours` is a child of `.search`, not its sibling.

Comment: Just updated my answer to be clearer. jQuery's `.next()` method won't find div.numberOfColours because it's a child of div.search, not a sibling. To search children of div.search, you need `.find()`

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce all your code to:

```
$('.numberOfColours').html( function(){return $(this).prev().find('li').length} )
```

```js
$('.numberOfColours').html(function() {
  return $(this).prev().find('li').length
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result-item-1" class="search" data-search-position="1" style="width: 50%;">
  <div class='item-colours-result'>
    <ul class="">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="numberOfColours">Test</div>
</div>



<div id="result-item-2" class="search" data-search-position="2" style="width: 50%;">
  <div class='item-colours-result'>
    <ul class="">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="numberOfColours">Test</div>
</div>



<div id="result-item-3" class="search" data-search-position="3" style="width: 50%;">
  <div class='item-colours-result'>
    <ul class="">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="numberOfColours">Test</div>
</div>
```

This selects the `numberOfColours` divs and iterates over them. [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) can be passed a function which will return the count based on the div it's on using `.prev()` and `.find()`.

Comment: @Sole Why did you remove the accepted check from my answer?

Comment: I clicked on the marked answer now, I clicked on yours by mistake the other day. I checked the code today and the answer is what is marked in the question.